# Using nano to edit a crontab

Tags: cron, nano

I haven't been able to get crontab to execute any of my scripts on start-up. I want to know why it doesn't work. Below is an example of me trying to use it, and I've tried to provide as much troubleshooting information as I can.

```
$crontab -l
no crontab for server
$crontab -e
#I scroll down to the bottom of the file and add the line below in
@reboot /usr/bin/teamspeak3-server_linux-amd64/ts3server_minimal_runscript.sh
#I make a carriage return at the bottom of the file
```

I press ctrl+o to save the file (as it opened in nano), and ctrl+z to exit. I now issue "crontab -e" to check the contents is there. The file shows up, just without the changes I made to it. I even tried adding just a commented line in the crontab file & this also doesn't save. Anyway I checked the script does actually work normally.

```
$cd /usr/bin/teamspeak3-server_linux-amd64/
$./ts3server_minimal_runscript.sh
```

It then gives loads of output as it reads the script and loads the script perfectly. So I ctrl+c to quit the application, and check the permissions.

```
$ls -l | grep ts3server_minimal
-rwxr-xr-x 1 server server bla bla bla ts3server_minimal_runscript.sh
```

So everyone can execute it. I reboot anyway, and find the application doesn't start. Why?

Comment: Nano shows a list of keybindings at the bottom of the window.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to use `Ctrl+x` to exit `nano` and install new crontab. `Ctrl+z` will just stop/send to background `nano` without installing new crontab. See attached screenshot:

[image: nano command bar]

Comment: OMG I'm gonna test it. If this fixes it I will love you forever and ever!

Comment: OMG it fixed it. I swear man. I have worked so long trying to figure this problem out. I LOVE YOU!

Comment: @johnsmith Editor Edit:  I added a screenshot to the answer.  If you don't see the Command Ribbon at the bottom, something is seriously wrong with your `nano` configuration,